# target machine actively refused it error

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, c#-3.0, windows-server-2008

I am having problem in downloading a file. I am using webclient to download the file. The code is working perfectly locally but not in the windows server 2008. I am getting an error

```
[Download File] Error: Download failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 125.7.64.41:8888
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
```

This is my code.

```
string url = "https://test.openseas.wlcl.com.au:8888/cruise/PA/priceSummary?AgentId=DIRECTAU&format=xml";
  WebClient mySSISWebClient = new WebClient();

  mySSISWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
  mySSISWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
  mySSISWebClient.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;

  // To save the file (and replace the existing file)
  mySSISWebClient.DownloadFile(url , Dts.Variables["User::LocalSourceFile"].Value.ToString())
```

Please can anyone help me why i am getting this error in the windows server 20087 and what should i do to make it work. Thanks

Comment: That error typically indicates that there is no web server listening at the specified IP address and port, or that the web server is configured to accept connections only from certain computers.

Comment: but this is working fine in local computers and even i tired from home its working fine but not from the server where i have uploaded this and its a windows server 2008 @HarryJohnston

Comment: You might get the same error message if the local firewall is configured to not allow outgoing connections, I'm not sure.

Comment: yes i checked the firewall and it is off :/ @HarryJohnston

Comment: Try turning it back on.  The networking stack sometimes does funny things  on Windows Server if the firewall is turned off.

Comment: Also, have you tried connecting to that URL in a web browser?  If that doesn't work either, then you can be sure the problem isn't related to your code.

Comment: it works in the browser but it say the connection is untrusted but then opens the page if i add exception then it asks for the username and password

Comment: I suppose the error message might mean that the server has rejected the username and password.  But I don't see why that would only happen on the one machine.  Unless it has something to do with IE Enhanced Security Configuration?  Perhaps try turning that off.

Comment: yes i see i am seeing  E Enhanced Security Configuration is enabled and now the page is not opening on chrom/IE on windows server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems that you describe sound like environmental issues, rather than code related.

I notice that the url you are using does not have a valid SSL certificate covering it.

If you are certain that the endpoint is and always will be safe, you can consider calling a method such as:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

before you attempt your connection. Please please please be aware, this is dangerous if you cannot utterly trust the website utterly. Typically I would only use this is you directly own the server, and are using it for casual  testing purposes.

Another potential problem could be a firewall configuration on the target machine hosting your endpoint.